# Modules architecture/distribution

Tags: angularjs

I was taking a look in this [nice Angular best practices repository](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y165) and I can't find a proper way to apply this pattern of modularization.

The author suggest importing all the other modules in the main app module, that seems to be a great idea for me, but in my perception it also means loading all the js files of the system when loading the page for the first time "into" the main module.

I'm looking this wrong? I'm I right? If I'm right, is there a workaround to avoid loaind all the js files? Should I be worried with the loading time of the js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular application is SPA, the page is loaded only once, all relevant JS files should be loaded at the time when the app is bootstrapped.

Angular doesn't officially support lazy loading to load additional module files on demand, doing this by patching the framework may cause more troubles than it may solve.

Bundling all modules with bundling systems (Webpack, Browserify, etc) into a single JS improves loading time and results in better performance than loading JS files selectively.

Comment: Thanks @estus, makes sense, since it's a SPA

Comment: I guess that Angular 2 may benefit from lazy loading with little help from HTTP/2. But for Angular and legacy browsers one big bundle does the job.